# Launch two different JAVA projects from the same GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I have two java projects. Both with runnable GUIs.

I would like to add a button in Project1 that when pressed opens Project2 application window and closes Project 1.

Since I am using MVC for both applications it would become too cluttered to just copy paste all the code from the first project into the other one, which is why I am looking for an easier alternative.

I have built a path between the two projects, but I can't seem to find a way to start the second application on a button press.

Comment: By clicking the button in project1 you can start a new process and make the new process as a daemon.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31187451/230513).

Answer (score 0):

i made you simple example of how to close JFrame after clicking a button and open new one.It is better if you write us the code you are useing note: i am not using MVC here

```
package test;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {
    private JButton btn;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public Test(){
        btn = new JButton("new window");

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());

    }

   private class addButtonWatcher implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame newWindow = new JFrame();
            newWindow.setVisible(true);
            newWindow.setSize(200,200);
            frame.dispose();

        }
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }

}
```